# ASP.NET troubles with updating DataGrid binded to custom DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datatable, missingmethodexception

I bind custom DataTable to DataGrid through ObjectDataSource, where i use SelectMethod and UpdateMethod. SelectMethod working great, but when I try to update row it's breaking by MissingMethodException. What should i do to fix this problem?

Sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your update method has the right parameters. For example if in your grid you have the following fields:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID:" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name :" />
```

your update method could look like this:

```
public void Update(int Id, string Name) 
{
    //...
}
```

Here's a [full example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/ADO.net-Database/ObjectDataSourcewithselectmethoddeletemethodupdatemethodinsertmethod.htm).

Comment: I'm sure that it's not because of parameters :(

Comment: Maybe you could show the relevant portion of your source code? Right now it's more of a guessing. Remember that the more information you provide the more rapidly and precisely the problem will be found.